# SQL Connection Error with Spring Boot

Tags: sql-server, spring, spring-boot

I am getting this "SQL state [null]; error code [0]; The connection is closed.; nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection is closed." Error when using springBootVersion = '1.5.4.RELEASE', JDBC driver version 6, and SQLServer 2008R2, using database mirroring. My connection settings:

```
    spring:
    datasource:
    initialize: false
    username: user1
    password: pass1
    type: org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource
    connection-properties: 
 statementPoolingCacheSize=200;failoverPartner=Server2;applicationName=${sp
    ring.application.name}
    url: jdbc:sqlserver://Server1;databaseName=DBName
    tomcat:
    initial-size: 10
    max-active: 50
    max-idle: 10
    max-wait: 1000
    validation-query: "SELECT 1"
```

Can you please help me in determining why this error is occurring?

Comment: is the server: `Server1` a valid hostname on your network? Does it resolve to the server you are hosting your SQL server on? Try executing `ping Server1` or `nslookup Server1` from a command prompt and verify the results are what you are expecting. Do you also need to specify a particular port?

Comment: Server1 is just given as a reference. We are passing a valid hostname. The connection string works if the database is online on either of database servers, it fails with the said error as soon as we failover.

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat native connection pool didn't work for failover and hikari.HikariDataSource was used.

```
 spring:
  datasource:
    initialize: false
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    username: user1
    password: pass1
    jdbcUrl: jdbc:sqlserver:/server1;databaseName=DB1;statementPoolingCacheSize=200;failoverPartner=server2;applicationName=${spring.application.name}
    dataSourceClassname: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource
    hikari:
      pool-name: TimeCommerce
      connection-timeout: 1000
      leak-detection-threshold: 5000
      maximum-pool-size: 40
      max-lifetime: 60000
      minimum-idle: 20
      connection-test-query: SELECT 1
      test-on-borrow: true
      test-on-connect: true
      test-on-return: true
```